# How can I reset my FRITZ! Box 3272 to its original factory settings?

Tags: fritzbox

I accidentally misconfigured my [FRITZ! Box 3272](https://en.avm.de/fileadmin/user_upload/EN/Manuals/FRITZ_Box/Manual_FRITZBox_3272.pdf): The web console in no longer accessible. There is no DHCP and it does not respond when using direct cable connection and manually assigned IP.

How can I reset it? There’s no button neither on the exterior nor inside of the device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### How can I reset it?

Several possibilities:

> If the FRITZ!Box user interface cannot be opened, this can have
> various causes. Work through the following steps in sequence until the
> error has been resolved.
>
> Enter `http://fritz.box` in the web browser.

...

> The FRITZ!Box has an “emergency IP address” (169.254.1.1) at which it
> can always be reached. You can use this IP ad-dress as follows:
>
> 1. Connect your computer to the “LAN 2” port of the  FRITZ!Box using a LAN cable.
> 2. If your computer is already connected with the FRITZ!Box over wireless LAN, clear the wireless connection.
> 3. Make sure that the computer obtains its IP address automatically (see page 96).
> 4. Clear all other connections between your FRITZ!Box and other network devices.
> 5. In the web browser, enter the address `169.254.1.1`.
> 6. When the FRITZ!Box user interface is displayed, enable the DHCP server of the FRITZ!Box:
>
>    In the user interface, select “Home Network / Network / Network
>    Settings”. Click the “IPv4 Addresses”button, enable the option “Enable
>    DHCP server”  and click “OK”

...

> Loading Factory Settings
>
> 1. In the FRITZ!Box user interface, select the “System / Re-set” menu.
> 2. Select the “Factory Settings” tab.
> 3. Click the “Load Factory Settings” button.
>
>    The FRITZ!Box is reset to its factory settings. All settings made
>    during operation will be overwritten.

Source: [Fritzbox 3272 Manual (pdf)](https://assets.avm.de/files/docs/fritzbox/fritzbox-3272/fritzbox-3272_man_en_GB.pdf)

Comment: Make sure to connect to LAN 2 port!